# Custom validator does not load in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I am trying to apply a custom validator to my model issue.rb:

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :no_followers, :title
  validates_presence_of :title
  validates_uniqueness_of :title, message: "Title should be unique!"

  validates_length_of :description, minimum: 10, maximum: 50
  validates_numericality_of :no_followers, allow_blank: true

  validates_with YesNoValidator

end
```

The validator is a file located at app/validators and contains the following:

```
class YesNoValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
    def validate record
        if record.title.include? "yes" && record.description.include? "No"
            record.errors[:title] << "Title has the word yes and description has the word no"
        end 
    end
end
```

I also tried to put it inside the lib folder but that also gives this error:

```
Routing Error

uninitialized constant Issue::YesNoValidator
```

At random F5'ing I sometimes get this error:

```
NoMethodError in IssuesController#new

undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass
```

So it seems like the file with the class is not loaded so I tried adding both the lib as well als the app/validators folder to the autoload_paths in application.rb. But this doesn't work either..

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: appliaction.rb :
    config.autoload_paths += %W[#{config.root}/app/validators]

Comment: have you tried moving your validator file to lib/validators and adding  `config.autoload_paths += %W[#{config.root}/lib/validators/]` to your application.rb?

Comment: @LeoCorrea still the same error.. sad enough

Comment: Class 'Issue' should have 'include ActiveModel::Validations' I believe.

Comment: It shouldn't include it as Active::Record already includes them.

Comment: Are you testing this local? Have you restarted the server?

Comment: Restarted server multiple times. Working on ubuntu server locally

Answer (score 6):

In your application.rb, add the app/validators path to the auto load path

```
config.autoload_paths += [Rails.root.join('app', 'validators').to_s]
```

or manually require the validator in the Issue.rb file.

Comment: Notice he mentioned he did have this in his autoload_paths.

Comment: For me it worked with: `Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'validators').to_s]`, this answer helped me.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't already, try restarting Rails server so that your changes in application.rb may be taken into account.